# Pandas DataFrame currency conversion

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I have DataFrame with two columns:

```
col1     | col2

20         EUR
31         GBP
5          JPY
```

I may have 10000 rows like this

How to do fast currency conversion to base currency being GBP?

should I use easymoney?
I know how to apply conversion to single row but I do not know how to iterate through all the rows fast.

EDIT:
I would like to apply sth as:

```
def convert_currency(amount, currency_symbol):
    converted = ep.currency_converter(amount=1000, from_currency=currency_symbol, to_currency="GBP")
    return converted


df.loc[df.currency != 'GBP', 'col1'] = convert_currency(currency_data.col1, df.col2
                                                                                  )
```

but it does not work yet.

Comment: Overwrite the said row, something like this `df['col1'] = formulae*df['col1']`. I think so

Comment: is there no fast option to intake currency ratios with pandas ? what is I have 30 diff currencies?

Comment: do you have exchange rates and in which form?

Comment: I do not. I thought I could use easymoney for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[20, 'EUR'], [31, 'GBP'], [5, 'JPY']], columns=['value', 'currency'])
print df

   value currency
0     20      EUR
1     31      GBP
2      5      JPY

def convert_to_gbp(args):  # placeholder for your fancy conversion function
    amount, currency = args
    rates = {'EUR': 2, 'JPY': 10, 'GBP': 1}
    return rates[currency] * amount

df.assign(**{'In GBP': df.apply(convert_to_gbp, axis=1)})

   value currency  In GBP
0     20      EUR      40
1     31      GBP      31
2      5      JPY      50
```

Answer (score 1):

Join a third column with the conversion rates for each currency, joining on the currency code in col2. Then create a column with the translated amount.

```
dfRate:
code | rate
EUR    1.123
USD    2.234

df2 = pd.merge(df1, dfRate, how='left', left_on=['col2'], right_on=['code'])

df2['translatedAmt'] = df2['col1'] / df2['rate']
```

Comment: it does it only for the first 'x' column where 'x' equals len of dfRate.

Comment: for all following columns it inputs NaN

Comment: Are you iterating through either of the DataFrames?