# Pandas DataFrame: Converting between currencies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that has entries that look like this

```
df
      price
0  42000SEK
1   1200EUR
2   2200EUR
```

I want to convert the entires that have Euros to SEK(swedish krona) and remove both SEK and EUR so i end up with this. (lets for simplicity say 1 EUR = 10 SEK)

```py
['42000']
['12000']
['22000']
```

With this line of code i can find the rows that has Euros.

```py
df[df.price.str.contains('EUR')]
```

but i dont know how to continue from here.

I could use this answer

[Pandas DataFrame currency conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227944/pandas-dataframe-currency-conversion)

if i could split on first letter in the cell but i cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: I don't think the assumption of the currency conversion is sensible here. so, the first part would be to split out the amount, and then do a second pass to get the actual ammount

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37683558/4799172) as the starting point for part A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try `replace` and `pd.eval`:

```
df["price"].replace({"SEK": "*1", "EUR": "*10"}, regex=True).map(pd.eval)
```

Output:

```
0    42000
1    12000
2    22000
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

This works nicely assuming you have no NaNs, and that there are only two currencies with one of them needing conversion. If you do have NaNs, fill them first. Finally, assign this back to the column to update the DataFrame.

Comment: I get this weird error: UndefinedVariableError: name 'price' is not defined

Comment: @JKnecht I have no idea what you copy pasted but you won't get that error if you run this code correctly and assign the result back. Please just copy the first line and assign the result back to `df['price'] = ...` and report back to me when you've tried that successfully.

Comment: Yes your code should work, there is something mysterious with the data. I need to clean it some more. Ill get back to you. Thanks btw.

Comment: more on `pd.eval`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval

Comment: @DavidErickson thanks for sharing! Oh wow, I think I know the dude who wrote that

Comment: This worked perfectly after doing some data cleaning, getting rid of strings and other garbage that shouldnt be in the column.

Answer (score 3):

### Original dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['42000SEK','1200EUR','2200EUR'],columns=['price'])
```

| price |
| --- |
| 42000SEK |
| 1200EUR |
| 2200EUR |

### Currency conversion dataframe

```
cc = pd.DataFrame({'from':['EUR','SEK'],'to':['SEK','EUR'],'rate':[10,.1]})
```

| from | to | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | SEK | 10 |
| SEK | EUR | .1 |

(may have dozens of currency pairs)

### Input fields separation

```
df['value'] = df['price'].str.slice(stop=-3).astype(int)

df['currency'] = df['price'].str.slice(start=-3)
```

| price | value | currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42000SEK | 42000 | SEK |
| 1200EUR | 1200 | EUR |
| 2200EUR | 2200 | EUR |

Applying conversion to EUR:

```
df['price in EUR'] = df['value']*df.merge(cc[cc.to=='EUR'].append({'from':'EUR','to':'EUR','rate':1},ignore_index=True),left_on='currency',right_on='from',how='left')['rate']
```

| price | value | currency | price in EUR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42000SEK | 42000 | SEK | 4200 |
| 1200EUR | 1200 | EUR | 1200 |
| 2200EUR | 2200 | EUR | 2200 |

Explanation:

- take only the conversion pairs to EUR: `cc[cc.to=='EUR']`
- ensure that there will be self-conversion, otherwise we won't have the lines that were EUR already: `.append({'from':'EUR','to':'EUR','rate':1},ignore_index=True)`
- join prices dataframe with conversion rates in a temporary column, note that the column currency is the same as the temporary column "from": `df.merge(...,left_on='currency',right_on='from',how='left')['rate']`
- multiply this temporary rate column with the prices column and append as a new column named 'price in EUR': `df['price in EUR'] = df['value']*...`

Now it is possible to convert many currencies to EUR, all you need is to feed the currency conversion dataframe (cc).

Comment: I really like this approach, it's smart and adaptable to other scenarios. The only thing I would change: You append the conversion from EUR to EUR (1:1) inside the conversion-formula - I would just add it to the initial data frame to keep the conversion formula clean.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['42000SEK', '1200EUR', '2200EUR'], columns=['price'])

# create multiplier
mult = df['price'].str.contains('EUR$').map({ True : 10, False : 1})

# extract values
values = df['price'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int)

df['price'] = values * mult
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   price
0  42000
1  12000
2  22000
```

For creating the multiplier column, you could use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

# create multiplier
mult = np.where(df['price'].str.contains('EUR$'), 10, 1)
```

If you want to keep all the info I suggest you use [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex for extracting the value and the currency, for example:

```
# extract multiplier and value, concat with existing df
res = pd.concat((df, df['price'].str.extract(r'(?P<value>\d+)(?P<currency>\D+)')), 1)

# create result and put it a column named total
res['total'] = res['value'].astype(int) * np.where(res['currency'].eq('EUR'), 10, 1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
      price  value currency  total
0  42000SEK  42000      SEK  42000
1   1200EUR   1200      EUR  12000
2   2200EUR   2200      EUR  22000
```

Comment: On values = df['price'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int) i get the error ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer - but df['price'].isna().sum() is equal to zero?

Comment: @JKnecht Try: `values = df['price'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: Now i did not get an error but now df"price"].value_counts() gives something very confusing. Your code should work but value_counts() now give me
3.000000e+12     265
5.000000e+12     252
etc, they are wrong by very much. (to not confuse you here df["price"] does not have three entries as in the question) But these values are 100.000.000 larger than they should be.

Comment: Could you add more meaningful examples to your question? I don't think there's anything wrong with the code ...

Comment: Yes your code should work, there is something mysterious with the data. I need to clean it some more. Ill get back to you. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the amount and currency, you can use regular expressions to extract the number part and non-number part separately:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['42000SEK', '1200EUR', '2200EUR']})
df['amount'] = df.price.str.extract(r'(\d+)')
df['currency'] = df.price.str.extract(r'([^\d]+)')
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
      price amount currency
0  42000SEK  42000      SEK
1   1200EUR   1200      EUR
2   2200EUR   2200      EUR
```

Comment: The output in "amount" doesn't look right.